# Does LocalStorage In HTML5 Qualify As A 'Database'?

Tags: database, html, local-storage

I've got a project which needs to be done.  However, one of the strict requirements of the project is that it should not involve any database.  My question is, does HTML5 localstorage qualify as a database?

Comment: Nope, localstorage isn't a database.

Comment: Depends on your definition of a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a **practical sense** I wouldn't consider it to be a database.

But from the definition it could qualify as a database, but not as a database management system (check wikipedia for the definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database ).

Sometimes the terms are used interchangeably, so it is a bit hard to give a definitive answer. Does the project specify what it means by that?

Comment: from the exact wording, "you are not permitted to use database at all in our project"

Comment: Can you ask them if you can store user configurations in the browser? =)

Comment: ha, will do that :P But seriously, this is such a thrash rule -.-